# How to change the browsermob ProxyServer Autodetect using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying unsuccessfully to change the ProxyServer Autodetect using selenium webdriver, on the code below `proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.AUTODETECT)` or `proxy.setAutodetect(true)` dont work; any help is really appreciated

```
    server = new ProxyServer(4444);
    server.start();
    server.newHar("xxxx");
    server.setCaptureContent(true);
    server.setCaptureHeaders(true);

    Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();
    proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.AUTODETECT);
    proxy.setAutodetect(true);

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

    webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using BrowserMob Proxy, which is a proxy server running locally. The `server.seleniumProxy()` method already sets the appropriate ProxyType, which is `ProxyType.MANUAL`. Setting `ProxyType.AUTODETECT` tells Firefox to auto-detect a network proxy, and of course Firefox has no way of knowing about the BrowserMob Proxy instance you are running locally.

If you remove these lines:

```
proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.AUTODETECT);
proxy.setAutodetect(true);
```

It should work as expected.